# C++ - make_shared when custom new and delete operators are defined

Tags: c++, c++11, effective-c++

Regarding the book "Effective Modern C++" from Scot Meyers, and the 21st item: "Prefer std::make_unique and std::make_shared to direct use of new":

"Some classes define their own versions of operator `new` and operator `delete`. Often, class-specific routines are designed only to allocate and deallocate chunks of memory of precisely the size of objects of the class. Such routines are a poor fit for `std::shared_ptr`’s support for custom allocation (via `std::allocate_shared`) and deallocation (via custom deleters), because the amount of memory that `std::allocate_shared` requests isn’t the size of the dynamically allocated object, it’s the size of that object plus the size of a control block. Consequently, using make functions to create objects of types with class-specific versions of operator `new` and operator `delete` is typically a poor idea."

Why is this a problem for `allocate_shared`/`make_shared`, if custom `new` and `delete` are called on same places as standard `new` and `delete`?

Construction:
Operator `new` is used just to construct the resource object, but `make_shared`/`allocate_shared` construct the constrol block.

Destruction:
With or without a custom deleter function specified, when `delete` is called, just the resource object should be removed. Cntrol block depends on reference and weak counts.

Why then the sentence: "Such routines are a poor fit for `std::shared_ptr`’s support for custom allocation (via `std::allocate_shared`) and deallocation (via custom deleters), because the amount of memory that `std::allocate_shared` requests isn’t the size of the dynamically allocated object, it’s the size of that object plus the size of a control block."?

Comment: Global versions of `operator new` can allocate any amount of memory. Class overloaded versions may be designed to allocate only amount of memory of a size of a given class. In `allocate_shared` / `make_shared`, you need to allocate memory for both the object and control block at once, which might not be possible with such class overloaded versions. Note that this has nothing to do with constructions, `operator new` is used here merely for allocation of raw uninitialized memory.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You mean that `operator new`, called by make functions , should allocate memory for the object + memory for the control block at once? I thought `new` is used just to allocate memory for the resource object and it is up to a make function to allocate memory for the control block? I should then implement creation of a control block as well in my custom `operator new`...

Comment: OK, I think I understand. Can you please just confirm if this is true? The control block is always created by `make_shared` (or `shared_ptr constructor`), but since make_shared performs only one memory allocation, `operator new` in that case needs to allocate enough memory (object + control block) but fills it just with the resource object. The rest is populated with the control block by make_shared. The same for deletion: Resource object is destroyed as long as reference count equals 0, but the whole memory is deallocated only after weak count becomes 0. Right?

Answer (score 1):

`std::make_unique` is fine, since it doesn't need any extra data (in general case).

Problem is `std::make_shared`. To make `std::shared_ptr` work some extra data are needed: strong reference counter, weak reference counter, deleter function pointer.

This means that when you do: `std::shared_ptr<Foo>{raw_pointer}`, `std::shared_ptr` will allocate own buffer to keep this data.
Now allocation is quite expensive so `std::make_shared` was introduced to optimize use of heap. It allocates memory which will hold `shared_ptr` data and pointed item side by side in single chunk of memory. It constructs pointed object [in place](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new).

So when you have custom operator `new` for some class, `std::make_shared` will not use it. On other head if you pass raw pointer to `std::shared_ptr` then you will have two blocks of memory.